# Closed formula for Sum

Tags: closed-form

How can I get a closed formula for this expression?

$$n^{n-1}\left(1+\sum_{i=2}^{n} {\frac{2^{i-1}\cdot n!}{i^{i-1}}}\right)$$

I tried to split the sum into

$$\sum_{i=2}^{n} n!=(n-1)\cdot n!$$

and

$$\sum_{i=2}^{n} {\frac{2^{i-1}}{i^{i-1}}} = \sum_{i=2}^{n} {\left(\frac{2}i\right)^{i-1}}$$

but I still can not solve it. Any Ideas?

Comment: The expression $\sum_{k=1}^n (1/k)^k$ doesnt seem to have a closed form.

Comment: @Nino: where did you encounter this expression, and what makes you believe it admits a closed-form expression?